# How to search for certain strings line by line for keywords

Tags: c++, text, iostream

I have a list of games with their categories in a text file as follows

```
MMO League Of Legends 
MMO World Of Warcraft 
Strategy Civilization 
Strategy Hearthstone 
Arcade Street Fighter 
Arcade PacMan 
AR Beat Saber 
AR Superhot
```

I need to search for each of the categories and whenever it finds a certain category to make an object of that category, for example

```
if (type == "MMO") game = new MMO(name, description);
```

How do I implement that search(line by line) so it uses everything after the category as the name. In other words I want it to save the whole name in the object not just the first word.

Thanks for the help!

This is my main fuction

```
int main()
{

ifstream inFile;
//Open the file
inFile.open("Games.txt");
//Check that file was opened successfully
if (!inFile) {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    exit(1); 
}



//Vector to store items
vector <Game*> games;

//All the items will be sorted using the Standard Library Sort() function.
void sort();


inFile.close();
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Open file as `fin` and recursively `do {fin >> type; getline(fin, name);} while(fin);`. Here `type` and `name` are of `std::string` type. NOTE: this will work only when it is guaranteed that your type is always a single word, i.e. type doesn't contain a space.

Comment: @DivyanshSingh the type is a single word, how will I implement what you said in my main function. I put in the line of code you gave me then I put the if statements or how will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first show you some example code and then give you the explanation. Please note: This is one of many possible solutions. And I added a lot of debug output, so that you can see, what happens behind the scenes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// A class hierachy
class Game {
protected:
    // The name. This will be inherited from all other ganes. No need to define it there
    std::string name{};
public:
    // Constructor with some debug output
    Game(const std::string& n) : name(n) { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call constructor for Game with name '" << name << "'\n"; }

    // Virtual Destructor with some debug output
    virtual ~Game() { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call destructor for Game\n";  }

    // This is a virtual oure function. It will prevent a direct instantiation of Game
    virtual void print(std::ostream&) const = 0;
};

class MMO : public Game {
public:
    // Constructor with some debug output. Call base constructor from Game and set name
    MMO(const std::string& n) : Game(n) { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call constructor for MMO with name '" << name << "'\n"; }

    // Virtual Destructor with some debug output
    virtual ~MMO() override { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call destructor for MMO\n"; }

    // Virtual function overrides base function and will be used polymorph
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override { os << name << " --> is of type MMO\n"; }
};

class Strategy : public Game {
public:
    // Constructor with some debug output. Call base constructor from Game and set name
    Strategy(const std::string& n) : Game(n) { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call constructor for Strategy with name '" << name << "'\n"; }

    // Virtual Destructor with some debug output
    virtual ~Strategy() override { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call destructor for Strategy\n"; }

    // Virtual function overrides base function and will be used polymorph
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override { os << name << " --> is of type Strategy\n"; }
};

class Arcade : public Game {
public:
    // Constructor with some debug output. Call base constructor from Game and set name
    Arcade(const std::string& n) : Game(n) { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call constructor for Arcade with name '" << name << "'\n"; }

    // Virtual Destructor with some debug output
    virtual ~Arcade() override { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call destructor for Arcade\n"; }

    // Virtual function overrides base function and will be used polymorph
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override { os << name << " --> is of type Arcade \n"; }
};

class AR : public Game {
public:
    // Constructor with some debug output. Call base constructor from Game and set name
    AR(const std::string& n) : Game(n) { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call constructor for AR with name '" << name << "'\n"; }

    // Virtual Destructor with some debug output
    virtual ~AR() override { std::cout << "DEBUG: Call destructor for AR\n"; }

    // Virtual function overrides base function and will be used polymorph
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const override { os << name << " --> is of type AR \n"; }
};

class GameList {
protected:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Game>> data{};
public:

    // Override extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, GameList& gl) {

        // Read all lines from the stream
        for (std::string type{}, name{}; std::getline((is >> type), name); ) {

            // Factory pattern. Create a class depending on the type
            if (type == "MMO") gl.data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<MMO>(name));
            else if (type == "Strategy") gl.data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Strategy>(name));
            else if (type == "Arcade") gl.data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Arcade >(name));
            else if (type == "AR") gl.data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<AR>(name));
            else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: invalid type read\n";
        }
        return is;
    }
    // Overide inserter operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const GameList& gl) {
        for (const std::unique_ptr<Game>& g : gl.data) {

            // This is a call of a polymorph function. G is a came and will call the correct function
            g->print(os);
        }
        return os;
    }
};

std::istringstream fileStream{ R"(MMO League Of Legends 
MMO World Of Warcraft 
Strategy Civilization 
Strategy Hearthstone 
Arcade Street Fighter 
Arcade PacMan 
AR Beat Saber 
AR Superhot )" };

int main() {
    // Define the Game list
    GameList gl;

    // Read games from file and add to game list
    fileStream >> gl;

    // Print out all games
    std::cout << gl;

    return 0;
}
```

Explanation:

First we build a class hierachy.

We start with class "Game" and then derive 4 classes from that: "MMO", "Strategy", "Arcade" and "AR".

All derivations are public, so that we can inherit the protected and public members and functions.

The base class contains the variable "name". And this is inherited by all derived classes. So, no need to define it there again.

The base class has a pure virtual function, designated by `= 0` after the function definition. That means that you cannot create / instantiate the class "Game" at all. But you can define functions, like the constructor and the destructor. All destructors in every class will just generate some debug output.

The Base class constructor will set the "name" of the game. And the constructors of the derived classes will call the base class contructor and set the "name" with that.

You can see that the `print` function has been designed as a virtual function in the base class "Game". So, we can override it in all derived classes.

Later, we access the `print` function through a pointer to `Game` and polymorphism will make sure that the correct function will be called.

OK, that was the "Game" class hierachy.

Next the "GameList".

This contains a vector of pointers to "Game". Please note. Nowadays we do not use any longer raw pointers for owned memory, but smart pointers like `std::unique_pointer`. This will prevent memory leaks and other catastrophies. We will also not use `new` any longer, but `std::make_unique`.

But, all this before your basic question: How to read the data? For that we override the extractor operator for the "GameList" class. With that, we can read from any stream like `std::ifstream` or `std::istringstream` or whatever other stream and use the `iostream` functionality.

So, what are we doing in this function?

First, we use a for loop to read all lines of the file. In the declaration part of the for loop, we declare 2 `std::string` variables: "type" and "name". Then comes the little bit tricky part.

We want to first read the "type" with `is >> type`. Then we want to read the rest of the line, until we hit the '\n'. This can be done with `std::getline(is, name)`.

You may have heard that extraction or insertion operations can be chained, like `std::cin >> a >> b >> c`. This works, because those operations return a reference to the original stream. So, `std::cin >> a` returns `std::cin` and then this will be used for the ">> b" and so on.

With that know how (`is >> type` will return is), we can use this and put it in the first parameter of the `std::getline` function which expects an "is" as the first parameter. So, we can write

```
std::getline((is >> type), name)
```

Then, first the type will be read and then then name.

Ok, understood. But why is that in the condition part of the `for` loop. For that you need to know that `std::getline` also returns a reference to the given stream, so again "is". And the stream have an overwritten `bool operator` and that will return the state of the stream, for example "end of file". And for that reason the result `std::getline` will be converted to a bool and can be used as condition.

In the `for` loop, after we have read the "type" we use a kind of factory pattern and create a new fitting derived class, and store a pointer to the base class in our internal `std::vector`.

In the inserter part of the "GameList" class, we retrieve all pointers to the base class via a range based for loop and call their virtual "print" function. And, by the wonder of polymorphism, the correct function will be called.

In main, for this example, I do not open a file, because I do not have files on StackOverflow. I use a `std::istringstreasm` instead, but you can of course use any other stream.

Main is then rather simple. We define a class "GameList" and then use the extractor operator, to read all data and create all classes.

Same is with the inseter operator. We insert the complete "GameList" into `std::cout` and calling the virtual `print` functions with that.

Some heavy stuff. But please try to digest the principle and then do your own apolication with that.

What a pity that nobody will read this . . .

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for your long and detailed explanation! I learned some new things from it. My question is, I already have all the classes and everything done. I got to the point where I can print out the names in my file. My question is how do I create new objects with the text I have. I want to search line by line and when it sees a word like MMO to create a new mmo object with the name of the game.

Comment: Look at the for loop. There it happens. The for loop reads line by line, and then, depending on the type, creates the needed class. This you should do in a similar way.